# Unresolved external due to missing virtual functions in linking

Tags: c++

I'm getting strange linking error in the main window. I also included the header files of those classes in main window. but still it can't link the virtual functions.

I'm using the following code that is in main:

```
S3W::IFields *recordsTx = pConnection->GetTransmittedFields();
    FieldsDataList *derived = dynamic_cast<FieldsDataList*>(recordsTx);

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        VarField& record = derived->CreateDataItem();
        FieldsDataList *fields = record.getChildrenDataList();


        VarField& fieldGeom1 = fields->CreateDataItem();
        fieldGeom1.SetKey("geom");
        double x = 47;
        double y = 16;
        fieldGeom1 = VarField::fromGPS(new ImplGps(x, y));
}
```

I'm getting the following link Error:

```
3>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct S3W::IFields & __thiscall VarField::getChildern(void)" (?getChildern@VarField@@UAEAAUIFields@S3W@@XZ)
3>MainWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct FieldsDataList * __thiscall VarField::getChildrenDataList(void)"
```

Here is the class definition of the Classes:

// pseudo code

```
class VarField : public S3W::IField
{

 virtual S3W::IFields& getChildern() override;
    // Inherited via IField
 virtual FieldsDataList * getChildrenDataList() override;

}
```

and IField is :

```
struct FieldsDataList;

namespace S3W
{
    struct IFields;

    struct IField : S3W::IListItem
    {
        enum class Type { NONE = 0, UINT = 1, DOUBLE = 2, STRING = 3 , GEOM = 4};
        virtual S3W::IGps* getGeom() = 0;
        virtual double getDouble() const = 0;
        virtual unsigned int getUint()   const = 0;
        virtual const char*  getString() const = 0;
        virtual const char*  getKey() const = 0;
        virtual Type getType() const = 0;
        virtual ~IField() { }
        IField() {} 
        virtual  IFields& getChildern()= 0; 
        virtual FieldsDataList* getChildrenDataList() = 0;
    };
```

Comment: You need to override them all.

Comment: I only see the *declaration* of those two functions, where is the *definition* of them?